# Hibernate and Glassfish : Class is not mapped

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, glassfish, mapping

First my apologies :

- For my bad english : I'm french so my vocabulary might be limited...
- If my problem has already be solved earlier. I searched through a lot of topic but couldn't find my answer.

I'm new to EJB and Hibernate and I'm trying to run a basic program which at some point uses a Hibernate Query to check if an entry is present in my database.
I'm "hot-deploying" it from Eclipse (Juno) to my GlassFish domain (Glassfish V3), and my database is a 5.5.28 MySQL server.

My problem is : when i use the Query.creatyQuery method to get the result I want, i get the org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: class is not mapped.

The problem is... it IS mapped. I'm using "annotation mapping" method... so no Hibernate hbm.xml mapping file involved. I tested it within a local Java Application, with the same exact syntax in my query, and it gave me the correct result.
I assume I forgot something while deploying but I really can't figure out what...
Here are the options I tested / facts I assume :

- If the exception occurs at that time of the query process, it means that my hibernate.cfg.xml file is found and correctly read (So I think that the required libraries from hibernate I placed in lib directories of Glassfish, as well as my JDBC driver).
- I tried to use .class.getName() to check wether or not I'm using the good class name in my query (I do know it's the class name that must be  used inside the query and not the correponding table in my database). It gave me the class name I expected, and didn't solve my problem.

Now for my code:

Login.java (package session)

```
package session;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import entity.*;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Login {


    public Login() {
    }

    public boolean confirmerLogin(String pseudo, String mdp){
        Session s = HibernateUtils.getSession();    
        Query q = s.createQuery("From Joueur where pseudo ='"+pseudo+"'");
        if(q.list().size()>=1)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }

}
```

The method confirmerLogin() return true or false wether the argument  is found or not in my database.

Joueur.java (package entity)

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class Joueur implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idJoueur;
private String mdp;
private String pseudo;

public Joueur() {
}

public int getIdJoueur() {
    return this.idJoueur;
}

public void setIdJoueur(int idJoueur) {
    this.idJoueur = idJoueur;
}

public String getMdp() {
    return this.mdp;
}

public void setMdp(String mdp) {
    this.mdp = mdp;
}

public String getPseudo() {
    return this.pseudo;
}

public void setPseudo(String pseudo) {
    this.pseudo = pseudo;
}

}
```

Then, Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">********</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bgwpf</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <mapping class="entity.Joueur"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And finally the exception :

```
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.8.Final}
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bgwpf]
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}

INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

    WARNING: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB Login method public boolean session.Login.confirmerLogin(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5119)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5017)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4805)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2004)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
at $Proxy98.confirmerLogin(Unknown Source)
at session.__EJB31_Generated__Login__Intf____Bean__.confirmerLogin(Unknown Source)
at ValiderLogin.doGet(ValiderLogin.java:26)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Joueur is not mapped [From Joueur where pseudo ='']
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3291)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3180)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1735)
at session.Login.confirmerLogin(Login.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1056)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1128)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5292)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:615)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5264)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5252)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
... 30 more
```

By the way, don't mind the comparison with an empty string (where pseudo =''), I get the same error with a not-null value.

I don't think there's other files involved but I will post anything else you could need.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you try changing your package name from session to something else , and then try as session is a reserved word.

Comment: Thank you for answering this fast Satya, and thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work...

Comment: change the name of package entity as well

Comment: I did it too, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The exception `QuerySyntaxException` is thrown when there is syntax error in SQL query. While using HQL you always have to use Classname instead of tablename. Also HQL queries are mostly case insensitive except for Java class names and properties.

HQL Documentation: [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2551)

> With the exception of names of Java classes and properties, queries
>   are case-insensitive. So SeLeCT is the same as sELEct is the same as
>   SELECT, but org.hibernate.eg.FOO and org.hibernate.eg.Foo are
>   different, as are foo.barSet and foo.BARSET.

But in your case you seem to be using correct case. Could you modify the query as below and check?

```
  public boolean confirmerLogin(String pseudo, String mdp){
        Session s = HibernateUtils.getSession();    
        Query q = s.createQuery("from Joueur j where j.pseudo=:pseudo");
        q.setParameter("pseudo", pseudo);
        if(q.list().size()>=1)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hello viralpatel, thank you for answering me. I tried your idea, it didn't work...Here is the exception I get, which seems to be the same kind as the one I got until there : `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Joueur is not mapped [from Joueur j where j.pseudo=:pseudo]`

Comment: But I just tried something new and it seems to work : when using Hibernate XML mapping file (hbm.xml) and its content auto-generated by Eclipse based on Joueur.java itself, it works! So I think that my declarations in my current hibernate.cfg.xml are somewhat wrong. I noticed that the DTD of my document is for Hibernate 3.0 whereas I work with Hibernate 4... I'm going to investigate this hint. I let you know!

Comment: Ok! sounds interesting :) The above code looks perfectly ok. Anyways, do post your analysis once you fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did some tests and researches and here is what I found :

First, the DTD : I thought the version of the DTD could be the same as the version of Hibernate, but it isn't the case. The last version of the DTD is currently 3.0. The last modifications done on the DTD can be found in the Hibernate Migration Guide 3.6.

My DTD version being 3.0, my problem doesn't come from it.

Then I compared the declarations in hbm.xml file auto-generated by Eclipse with the annotations I have on my entity (Joueur.java).
I missed almost half of them, but they were all optional. I had high hopes when I noticed that I had forgotten the annotation Table(name=""), but it didn't do the trick either...

I have no clue for further researches, plus I already found the answer to my problem, even if it means using xml files instead of annotations which I prefer. I'll assume GlassFish doesn't handle annotations regarding Hibernate entities yet...

So I'm going to tag my question as answered, but if by chance anyone has a solution, please let me now!

Thank you Satya and Viral Patel for your suggestions!